# Power Bi dealing with repeated instruments from REDCap

Tags: powerbi, redcap

I have data like this:

[image]

It comes from REDCap, and as you may be able to tell, the data in the far right columns are repeated variables about each "protocol_title" (the far left column).  I.e. "Love it" and "I want a disc instead" are both about "study 2"

[image]

I've imported the data into Power Bi and currently I have this:

[image]

What I'd like is for the top left visual to only have one row per study (with columns such as principal investigator and method of image transfer, i.e. columns that had data in the first row) and a visual on the lower left with all the right-most columns.

By switching the top visual from a table to a matrix I can kinda accomplish this:

[image]

But it adds a bunch of unnecessary columns.  As an alternative I thought I could add a filter to the top visual that would filter to "redcap_event_name"=="protocol_information" which would only be those top rows.... but given the visuals are linked, if I do that it removes everything from the bottom visual.   I'd like to keep the link between the visuals so that if I select "study2" in the top visual, it'll highlight relevant study 2 information in the bottom one.

So my question is:  what's the best approach for making the visuals I want?  Are there special settings for visuals?  Do I need to do something to the data first in the query? How should I go about this?

Comment: None of your screenshots are readable.

Comment: They should be now, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to rework you data structure. At first glance, your flat source table could be parsed into two tables :

- Protocol
- Survey

This can be done in PowerQuery.

For `Protocol` :

1. Select columns A to R.
2. Filter on `redcap_event` (?) starts by "protocol_info"
3. Delete empty rows

For `Survey`

1. Select columns A (to keep the protocol ID and be able to link both tables), T and U.
2. Filter on `redcap_event` (?) starts by "survey"
3. Delete empty rows.

You should end up with the two table with a one-to-many relationship between `Protocol[Protocol_ID]` (column A) and `Survey[Protocol_ID]` (same)

And it should make everything much easier: visuals, calculations...